# Can you help me write up this equation in latex properly?

Tags: equations

I am trying to write up this equation properly in latex so as for the formulas to align neatly :

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
  M_{u,t}(\mathbf{n})=\min_{
    \substack{i=1,2,\ldots,m\\
      E_{t,i}(\mathbf{N})=\min_{
        \substack{\mathbf{x}\in V_{u, t}^{i}(\mathbf{n})}}
      {E_{t, i}(\mathbf{x})}}}
  \left\{Z_{u, t, t+v(\mathbf{N})}(\mathbf{n} ;
    \mathbf{N})+\Psi_{t+v(\mathbf{N})+1}\right\}
\]



\end{document}
```

[image]

You can probably see how I wish the formula to appear from the content of the formula.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Unfortunately your code cannot be complied, as it is incomplete and it seems to contain errors, so it's hard to understand what you're looking for. Can you clarify the question?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SE. First and foremost, your code doesn't even compile, so please fix the errors so that we don't have to guess what you intended to write. Also, please use more whitespace and line breaks; your code in its current form is very hard to read.

Comment: it is rather hard to guess how you want this to look and it makes no output at all currently due to errors. I edited it so it had matching `{}` and produces some output, is that what you intended to show?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle sorry. Thank you for correcting it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd avoid those complicated staggered limits:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{multline*}
M_{u,t}(\mathbf{n})=
\min\Bigl\{Z_{u, t, t+v(\mathbf{N})}(\mathbf{n};\mathbf{N})+\Psi_{t+v(\mathbf{N})+1}:
\\
i=1,2,\dots,m,\quad
E_{t,i}(\mathbf{N})=\!\!\min_{\mathbf{x}\in V_{u, t}^{i}(\mathbf{n})}\!\! E_{t, i}(\mathbf{x})
\Bigr\}
\end{multline*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Maybe with `\Bigm|` instead of `:`, but it depends on how you use set builder notation in your document.

[image]

I really don't think that

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
  M_{u,t}(\mathbf{n})=\min_{
    \substack{\mathstrut i=1,2,\dots,m \\[0.2ex]
      E_{t,i}(\mathbf{N})=\min\limits_{\mathbf{x}\in V_{u, t}^{i}(\mathbf{n})}
      {E_{t, i}(\mathbf{x})}}}
  \{Z_{u, t, t+v(\mathbf{N})}(\mathbf{n} ;
    \mathbf{N})+\Psi_{t+v(\mathbf{N})+1}\}
\]

\end{document}
```

would be an improvement.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, these equations look very nice. However I would prefer if it was written with all the min arguments below min since this is the style of all my previous equations and of the previous papers whose methods I am using.

Comment: @Stel That would leave big blobs of white space and be really confusing. Anyway, I added the code.

Comment: I remember the old story about the Carthaginians: every year they killed their first born sons, to appease the fire god Moloch. It worked: every year, for a thousand years, Moloch did not rain down fire and destroy the world. Sometimes I need to reconsider my decisions, rather than continue to use style of my previous equations and papers.

Comment: @BenjaminMcKay But at some point the Romans arrived, and…